# Django CMS initial migration fail

Tags: django, django-cms

I've gone through the installation steps on the Django-CMS site, and I am unable to do the initial migration.  I keep getting the following error:

if x['BACKEND'] == 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'][0]
KeyError: 'BACKEND'

Googling this error yields nothing.  I've scoured setup.py and I'm not seeing anything like this.  I'm just lost and a bit worried that the install instructions may be a bit dated, as I also had to remove the list of extra apps they suggest adding to INSTALLED APPS because none of them were found.  Anyway, I'm down to this error, I think.  Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: The traceback will tell you where the error occurs.

Comment: Speaking of the traceback, can you post it? It'd be helpful to know what you may have encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss the `'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates'` entry inside the `TEMPLATES` setting, in your settings file. Check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I ran into the same error, so the solution might be useful to somebody else too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all of your entries are listed in single dictionary. For instance, if you are following along with the ['Integrating a third-party application' tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/third_party.html), when they show the following...

```
'OPTIONS': {
         'context_processors': [
             # ...
             'aldryn_boilerplates.context_processors.boilerplate',
             ],
         'loaders': [
             # ...
             'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader',
             ],
         },
     },
```

...you need to integrate it into your existing dictionary. Your TEMPLATES array would then look like the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
            'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            'cms.context_processors.cms_settings'
            'aldryn_boilerplates.context_processors.boilerplate',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
            'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader',
        ],
    },
}
]
```